# Is it necessary to have selector's name in same case in css and html?

Tags: html, css

Is it necessary to have selector's name in same case in css and html?

is it ok ?

```
<div id="HEADER"> </div>

#header{...}
```

or this is necessary?

```
<div id="HEADER"> </div>

#HEADER{...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names and IDs are case sensitive, so they must have the same casing.

Therefore, `div.MyClass` is **not** the same as `div.myClass`.

Element (in HTML) and pseudo-class (everywhere) names are not case sensitive, so `DIV:hover` **is** the same as `div:HOVER`.

For more information, read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your second example should be #HEADER{...} but the answer is... some browsers are case sensitive if you use an XHTML doctype. See here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqcase.htm